# How to load a UIViewController in landscape mode if its parent is in Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to load a ViewController in landscape mode from a portrait parent. Parent is got fixed for portrait, it wont change its orientation, however the child view controller whichever is got pushed from the parent also loading portrait initially irrespective of the device orientation (if we rotate the device few more times then the orientation set properly for childs). So how to load child properly in initial time itself.

or

Is there any way I can set the orientation programatically, so that I can use it in ViewWillAppear method.
 Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your child UIViewController set these two methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

In parent UIViewController do:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

If you want to present navigation bar in child:

```
DetailViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
controller.title = @"Child";
```

You'll have to subclass UINavigationController with the two methods mentioned above instead in the child view controller.

```
MyNavigationController *nav = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have problem in initial loading only. After view loads in portrait mode, if I change the orientation it will change properly.

Comment: If you are pushing to the same UINavigationController it's impossible. You'll have to present modalViewController. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

Comment: May be that was the problem.. as I asked in my question, Is there any way to do it programatically after child loads (may be in ViewWillAppear method)

Comment: It worked like a charm. But, I need navigation bar at the top as well which is not coming when we present view controller instead of push view controller..? What will be the solution for it ?

Comment: Instantiate another `UINavigationController` with child controller as root controller. And present navigation controller instead of a child controller. If you want a back button, you'll have to implement it by yourself. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Try this sample Project...........

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrsz4dpeolpeu23/RotationDmeo.zip

Comment: it working but have several warning . Will you please update the project?

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, you just add this methods to your child view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft / Right;
}
```

To present your view use

```
[self presentViewController:viewController...]
```

And your view is presented in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in view did appear or will appear,

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice]performSelector:@selector(setOrientation:) withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)];
```

Before that Enable all 4 orientations in your .plist

Add this on AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    UIViewController *cont=self.vc;

    if([cont isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]])
    {
         NSUInteger orientations =  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

        NSLog(@"Landscape");

        return orientations;
   }

    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    return orientations;
}
```